# FCM not receive on gadget

Tags: android

I have just implemented FCM push notification to my webview app, when I run my app on the emulator and send a notification from FCM console, my app will receive the notification when my app running in background. But when I build and apk file and install it on my gadget, the same notification will never receive on my gadget. How to fix this problem?

```
package com.example.intawebapp.activity;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

and

```
    package com.example.intawebapp.activity;

    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

        public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
            // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
            // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
            // message, here is where that should be initiated.
            Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
```

and the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.intawebapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".activity.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <service android:name=".activity.FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: My gadget can receive notification after I put SHA 1 in FCM console

Answer (score 0):

My gadget can receive notification now after I put SHA 1 in FCM console